# Duplicate definition of identifiers allowed in eval in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

While playing around with Racket in DrRacket, I accidently  entered in the
interactions window.

> (define x 7)
>   (define x 8)

and DrRacket allowed it, i.e.  I didn't get a "duplicate definition of
identifiers error message.

So to try and figure out what was going onI then entered this in the
definitions window of DrRacket:

*Code snippet A*

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)  
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))  
(eval '(begin (define x 7) (define x 8)) ns)  
(eval 'x ns)
```

and still no "duplicate definitions error".

I then tried this also in the definitions window:

*Code snippet B*

```
(define x 9)  
(define-namespace-anchor a)  
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))  
(eval '(begin (define x 7) (define x 8)) ns)  
(eval 'x ns)
```

and I got the error message: `cannot redefine a constant x`.

Can someone explain to me why in code snippet A  in the definitions window
(and also simply entering  `(define x 7)`  followed by `(define x 8)` in the interactions window) doesn't give me a duplicate definitions error.

Comment: Wait... I'm super-confused.  Didn't you just ask this on the mailing ... oh... no one responded. Sigh.

Comment: @John: That just goes to show, mailing lists need a rep system too. :-P

Comment: Sadly, the answer on the mailing list--in this case, Matthew answered a few hours ago--is likely to be a great deal more authoritative. As it was in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an explanation of this answer on the mailing list by Matthew Flatt:
 http://www.mail-archive.com/users@racket-lang.org/msg09340.html

Answer (score 9):

Historically, Scheme (not Racket) has always allowed re-definitions. A re-definition at the top level is equivalent to the mutation of an existing binding.  Racket has tightened this up a bit, in that code at the top level *of a module* is not allowed to re-define an identifier. However, the old behavior persists in the "top level" that's used for "eval" and the interactions window.

I may be missing details here, but I believe that everything I'm telling you is true.